# if there a way to check does the author have perms but if i am (bot owner) is the author it works regardless

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want my code to check if the the message author has perms to delete messages but at the same time if I(bot owner) am the author i want it to work regardless of perms

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['clear'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def purge(ctx , number : int = None):
    if number is None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter number of messages to delete with the command")
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = number + 1)
```

here is my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `commands.check_any` decorator

```py
@client.command(aliases=["clear"])
@commands.check_any(commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True), commands.is_owner())
async def purge ...
```

#### Reference:

- [`commands.check_any`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check_any)